# Null session with url aliasing

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

jboss 5.1
I have an application(war) deployed to a proxied server.
I put a logout servlet in the jboss deploy directory and mapped it in server/default/deployers/jbossweb-deployer/web.xml so any deployed app could use it.
We want users to be able to access the site using the base url:

```
http://ourAwesomeSite/
```

vs the war name:

```
http://ourAwesomeSite/ourAwesomeApp.home.seam
```

To do this I added this to deploy/ROOT.war/index.html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/ourAwesomeApp"/>
```

But now my logout servlet no longer works correctly.

in the doGet method session is always null, so I can't invalidate the session.  Users logout, and their current session is not invalidated and anyone who logs in after(unless the browser is closed) gets the previous user's session.
LogoutServlet:

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException, 
                ServletException {
            System.out.println("**********************  logout servlet");

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
// session is always null
            if (!this.isSessionInvalid(request) && session != null) {
                System.out.println("invalidating user session ... maybe");
                session.invalidate();

            }
            System.out.println("redirecting to SSO logout");
            response.sendRedirect("https://ssologoutpage/logout.html");

        }
```

server/default/deployers/jbossweb-deployer/web.xml entry and mapping:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.whatev.log.security.session.management.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/logout.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I'm not sure how the request session is getting set to null.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at Setting up Virtual Hosts rather than redirecting to another web-application page.Please find the [Setup Virtual Hosts](http://wiki.unixcraft.com/display/MainPage/Application+Virtual+Hosts)

Comment: thanx Phani, I got rid of ROOT.war and set `<context-root>/</context-root>`  in our app's jboss-web.xml.  That worked, not sure why though.  One more question, setting context-root took away access using the original url, so users can access us via `http://ourAwesomeSite/` but not `http://ourAwesomeSite/ourAwesomeApp`  Is there a way I can configure it so both will work?  I'm behind an apache server which is hosted virtually.

Comment: Well, I didn't try that but I'm sure that would allow us by default.